# At least one X but no Ys Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I come across this pattern occasionally and I haven't found a terribly satisfactory way to solve it.

Say I have a `employee` table and an `review` table. Each employee can have more than one review. I want to find all the `employee`s who have at least one "good" review but no "bad" reviews.

I haven't figured out how to make subselects work without knowing the employee ID before hand and I haven't figured out the right combination of joins to make this happen.

Is there a way to do this *WITHOUT* stored procedures, functions or bringing the data server side? I've gotten it to work with those but I'm sure there's another way.

Comment: It's certinaly possible, but please give the relevant structure from your table! (ie the column(s) relating `employee` to `review` and how you determine whether a review is good or bad (is there some column for that?))

Comment: I wish there were a better question title for this; unless that's a reasonably well-known phrase, I think it could be challenging to find in searches. Maybe "Get only records for which an aggregate join on another table has one condition but not another"?

Comment: You seek the intersection of a cross join between A & B and a semi-anti join between A & C.  "A" represents employee, "B" good reviews, and "C" bad reviews.

Comment: I didn't provide the whole schema because this is a much simplified version of the logic involved in determining a "good" or a "bad." Given all of the answers below, I definitely think I can improve on my current model! :) Thanks much!

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm all ears if you can think of one. Your suggestion seems advanced. As in, if I knew how to phrase the question like that, I would probably already know the answer! ;)

Comment: The contents of what the question title says has nothing to do with your own capabilities; I just think it's not really matching any terms people might be searching for. All I could come up with long, tedious and partially strangled sentences. What I have above was about the best I could come up with.

Comment: Given that this is basically a reporting question, you might consider making a rollup table that you fill periodically with employee key, # good reviews, # bad reviews for whatever time period. Then your query is pretty simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you haven't posted your DB Structure, I made some assumptions and simplifications (regarding the `rating` column, which probably is number and not a character field). Adjust accordingly.

### Solution 1: Using Joins

```
select distinct e.EmployeeId, e.Name
from employee e
left join reviews r1 on e.EmployeeId = r1.EmployeeId and r1.rating = 'good'
left join reviews r2 on e.EmployeeId = r2.EmployeeId and r1.rating = 'bad'
where r1.ReviewId is not null --meaning there's at least one
and r2.ReviewId is null --meaning there's no bad review
```

### Solution 2: Grouping By and Filtering with Conditional Count

```
select e.EmployeeId, max(e.Name) Name
from employee e
left join reviews r on e.EmployeeId = r.EmployeeId
group by e.EmployeeId
having count(case r.rating when 'good' then 1 else null end) > 0
and  count(case r.rating when 'bad' then 1 else null end) = 0
```

Both solutions are SQL ANSI compatible, which means both work with any RDBMS flavor that fully support SQL ANSI standards (which is true for most RDBMS).

As pointed out by @onedaywhen, the code will not work in MS Access (have not tested, I'm trusting in his expertise on the subject).

But I have one saying on this (which might make some people upset): I hardly consider MS Access a RDBMS. I have worked with it in the past. Once you move on (Oracle, SQL Server, Firebird, PostGreSQL, MySQL, you name it), you do not ever want to come back. Seriously.

Comment: "SQL ANSI compatible, which means both work with any RDBMS flavor" -- this is not a true statement. For example, your code does not work on Access (which is a DBMS that has its own SQL that is not standard SQL compliant) nor Rel (which is a RDBMS but not a SQL product).

Comment: @onedaywhen I updated my answer to make that a true statement. But I have one point (which might make some people upset): I hardly consider MS Access a RDBMS

Comment: @onedaywhen I'm actually curious now. Which of the solutions do not work in Access? What SQL construct is not supported by Access?

Comment: Access does not support CASE expressions; instead has a proprietary `SWITCH()` function. No product that supports the SQL standard is relational (nulls, duplicate rows, column ordering, etc). Please do not use the word relation or its derivatives when you mean SQL. Thanks for listening :)

Comment: @onedaywhen Thanks for the input. That means the first solution is good for Access, but not the second. The good thing about this community is that we are always listening. :) Don't forget to upvote if you believe the solutions are good for OP's problem!

Comment: Nice try but I'm unlikely to upvote an answer that equates 'SQL' and 'relational'. I upvoted Griffin's answer because they more or less name-checked the underlying relational operators (antijoin and semijoin). Better luck next time :)

Answer (score 5):

The question -- return rows on side A based on nonexistence of a match in B -- (employees with No "Bad" reviews) describes an "anti-semi join".  There are numerous ways to accomplish this kind of query, at least 5 I've discovered in MS Sql 2005 and above.

I know this solution works in **MSSQL 2000 and above**, and is the most efficient out of the 5 ways I've tried in MS Sql 2005 and 2008. I am not sure if it will work in MySQL, but it should, as it reflects a rather common set operation.

Note, the `IN` clause gives the subquery access to the `employee` table in the outer scope.

```
SELECT EE.*
FROM   employee EE
WHERE
    EE.EmpKey IN (
      SELECT RR.EmpKey
      FROM   review RR
      WHERE  RR.EmpKey = EE.EmpKey
        AND  RR.ScoreCategory = 'good'
    ) 
  AND
    EE.EmpKey NOT IN (
      SELECT  RR.EmpKey 
      FROM    review RR
      WHERE   RR.EmpKey = EE.EmpKey
        AND   RR.ScoreCategory = 'bad'
    )
```

Comment: Griffin, I re-spaced that SQL, as it was hurting my eyes to look at and I found it a little bit of a challenge to space it out using my own esthetic approach. (*Note, I did leave the lineups following the far-left keywords, so I didn't completely do everything I would normally do myself...*) I apologize in advance if that offends you, and won't mind if you choose to revert it. However, I do think it is a productive improvement, FWIW. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. The particular syntax depends on how you store 'good' and 'bad' reviews.

Suppose you had a `classification` column in `review` that had values 'good' and 'bad'.

Then you could do:

```
SELECT employee.*
FROM employee
JOIN review 
 ON employee.id=review.employee_id
GROUP BY employee.id
HAVING SUM(IF(classification='good',1,0))>0 -- count up #good reviews, > 0
   AND SUM(IF(classification='bad',1,0))=0  -- count up #bad  reviews, = 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ???? FROM employee,review
WHERE employees.id = review.id
GROUP BY employees.id
HAVING SUM(IF(review='good',1,0)) > 1 AND SUM(IF(review='bad',1,0)) = 0
```