# SELECT users who have downvoted but never upvoted

Tags: php, mysql

So, I thought I was getting pretty good at MySQL until I ran into this idea:

I have a table logging "votes" (aptly named `votes`) with these fields:

- `id`: The vote's unique ID.
- `user`: Unique User ID of the person who voted
- `item`: ID of item they're voting on
- `vote`: The vote they cast SET('up','down')

Now, I'm trying to come up with an SQL way to find users whose only votes are downvotes.  I know of a way to write it procedurally in php after querying most of the data out of the table but it seems really, really inefficient to do that way when only a few queries could find this out.

Ideally I want my result to just be a list of users who have 0 upvotes (as being in the table means they have voted, so they only downvote) and maybe the number of downvotes they've cast.

Any ideas on how I should approach this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Atleast one X but no Ys Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626965/atleast-one-x-but-no-ys-query)

Comment: Oh wow, that is very similar, nice!

Comment: I left a comment on the other question (which I think has a good answer and was a bit earlier) that it needs a better, more SEO-friendly title. I don't know what that would be, per se, but I don't think *[At least one X but no Ys Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626965/at-least-one-x-but-no-ys-query)* well enough works for to describe what it means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT user, SUM(IF(vote='down',1,0)) AS numDownVotes
FROM votes
GROUP BY user
HAVING SUM(IF(vote='up',1,0))=0   -- 0 upvotes
   AND SUM(IF(vote='down',1,0))>0 -- at least 1 downvotes
```

I can't help but feel there's a neat `GROUP BY user, vote` way to do this though.

Comment: Output is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: That is pretty nifty, and gets around the "problem" of not being able to match `WHERE` an `ALIAS` is used for a subquery.

Answer (score 3):

```
select user, count(user)
from votes
where user not in (
  select distinct user
  from votes
  where votes = 'up')
```

Comment: This counts the number of downvotes each user has given; but if a user has both downvoted and upvoted, it will still include them (& their downvote total).

Comment: This is close, but count(user) is giving the wrong value (in this case, 20 instead of 2.)

Comment: Also, it is only returning one row with one user ID (the data has more than one)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't checked the syntax or anything, but this comes to mind...

```
SELECT user 
FROM votes 
GROUP BY user 
  HAVING SUM(IF(vote = 'up', 1, 0)) = 0 
     AND SUM(IF(vote = 'down', 1, 0)) > 0
```

Comment: This looks very promising, but any way to identify exactly how many downvotes each user has cast?

Comment: Sure, you should be able to add SUM(IF(vote = 'down', 1, 0)) AS DownVotes to the column specification.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select v.user from votes v where
   0=(select count(a.vote) from votes a where a.user=v.user and a.vote='up' group by user) u 
 and 
  0 <(select count(a.vote) from votes a where a.user=v.user and a.vote='down' group by user) d
  group by user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything wrong with doing it on the database call? Something like:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM votes WHERE vote = 'down'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 $curID = $rows['id'];
}
```

Comment: A user can have multiple votes (meaning multiple entries in the table). This query returns one record for each vote, not each user, and it will also return users who voted _anything_ down, even if they voted other things up.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection

$query = "SELECT user, COUNT(user) FROM votes where vote == 'down' GROUP BY user"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "User : ". $row['type'] ." has ". $row['COUNT(user)'] ." downvote/s.";
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```